# How do I call a sub returned by reference by a Perl closure?

Tags: perl, closures

I'm trying to make subroutine closure working like an object.
However, I cannot call the returned subs references properly.

I receive `Not a CODE reference at .\closure.pl line 22.` error.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub number {
    my ($value) = @_;

    my $val = sub {   $value };
    my $inc = sub { ++$value };
    my $dec = sub { --$value };

    my %api = (
        'val' => \$val,
        'inc' => \$inc,
        'dec' => \$dec,
    );

    return %api;
}

my %numb = number(42);
$numb{'inc'}->();
print $numb{'val'}->();
```

How to fix the code?

**Code fixed**

Yes, of course, an anonymous definition must return a reference. it means that it can be put directly in the `%api`. Perl doesn't complain and works like a charm :)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub number {
    my ($value) = @_;

    my %api = (
        'val' => sub {   $value },
        'inc' => sub { ++$value },
        'dec' => sub { --$value },
    );

    return \%api;
}

my $m = number(14);
my $n = number(41);

$m->{'dec'}->();
$n->{'inc'}->();

print $m->{'val'}->() . "\n"; # -> 13
print $n->{'val'}->() . "\n"; # -> 42
```

Comment: You are creating an extra level of reference. Just pass `$val`, `$inc`, etc as the values, no backslash. `sub` in an expression already returns a reference.

Comment: @Grinnz, thank you! it works. Please post your note as an answer in order to accept it. Please, contribute to how I can improve the example according to the Perl Best Practices.

Comment: Perl Best Practices are just suggestions, and many of those from the book of that name have not aged well. My current suggestions are mostly encompassed in [this Perl::Critic policy theme](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Freenode) and this example seems fine to me, though returning a hash reference rather than a hash (which gets flattened into a list, then assigned back to a hash) is more common.

Comment: I like how you changed `return %api;` to `return \%api;`. The former returns a list of keys and value (since one can't return a hash from a sub), which means the hash must be reconstructed on the outside. That's a lot of needless work.

Comment: Re "*Perl Best Practices are just suggestions, and many of those from the book of that name have not aged well.*", Not quite. The good practices in the book are still good practices. It's just that the book included some practices that were considered poor even when the book was published.

Comment: @ikegami The big one is that it recommends `return;` over `return undef;` which falls prey to context sensitivity traps. Was that considered a poor practice at the time? (I only really was witness to the aftermath of that.)

Comment: @Grinnz, For such a specific question, I can only speak for myself, and yes, I have always considered return; in a sub expected to return a scalar to be a bad practice. But that wasn't an isolated case. When the book came out, we on PerlMonks regularly had to point out on that PBP was one person's opinion and not the views of the community as a whole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in [perlref](https://perldoc.pl/perlref#4.), the `sub` keyword without a name creates an anonymous subroutine and returns a reference to it. So you don't need to create another level of reference using the backslash; just pass the reference you already have as the value in the hash.